# Describing a Quotient Topology

Tags: general-topology

A question in an assignment is the following:
$X=\mathbb{R}$ and $a \sim b$ if either $a=b=0$ or $a \neq 0 \neq b$. Describe $X/\sim$.

Here's my solution:
Since we know the natural map $p: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}/\sim$ is continuous. I need to consider this question: For what $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is $f^{-1}([x])$ open? And since, for any non-zero $x$, $f^{-1}([x]) = \mathbb{R} \backslash 0$. Therefore $\mathbb{R}/\sim$ is a topological space with the topology $\mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{R}/\sim}=\{{\mathbb{R} \backslash 0}, \emptyset\}$. Since $[x] = \{y \in \mathbb{R} \ \vert \ y \neq 0\} = \mathbb{R} \backslash 0$, for any non-zero $x$.

Am I going wrong anywhere?

Comment: It's a little more complicated than that. $\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}$ is a **point** in $\mathbb R/\sim$. Also, the topology must contain the entire space. So first list all the points...

Comment: Right, I understand that. But the $\mathbb{R}/\sim$ only contains 2 points $0, \mathbb{R\backslash 0}$. And {0} is closed, since $f^{-1}({0})=0$. So what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set $X/\sim$ consists of two points, namely $[0]$ and $[1]$. The inverse image of $[1]$ is $(-\infty,0)\cup (0,\infty)$, thus $\{[1]\}$ is open in $X/\sim$. Moreover, $\{[0]\}$ is not open. Therefore the topology on $X/\sim$ is $\{\{[0],[1]\},\{[1]\},\emptyset\}$.

Comment: Right! I forgot the whole space! Thanks, got it!